# Cookie exists but Request.Cookies throws a NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I mean the title says it all...

I'm creating a cookie:

```
var cookie = new HttpCookie("smbm");
cookie.Values.Add("si", store.Id.ToString());
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Then I'm requesting it:

```
if (_storeId == 0)
{
    int.TryParse(Request.Cookies["smbm"]["si"], out _storeId);
}
```

I've verified that the cookie exists, by checking Application tab in Chrome dev tools:

[image]

Why then is the Request in the if statement throwing a NullReferenceException?

Comment: What value do you get if you call `Request.Cookies["smbm"];`?

Comment: @vbnet3d also NullReferenceException

Comment: @Ortund : not sure. anything to do with cookie domain ?

Comment: Don't think so... Cookie says localhost:4811 and that's the URL I'm working with

Comment: okay so does it matter if the query for the cookie value is in a user control?

Answer (score 0):

Well, just a possible solutions: when you use response.cookies it gives you all the cookies of the client. Using add adds a variable. Meaning, try replace request with response. I am a vb.net asp.net coder, I checked all methods. I can use after cookies.item(cookiename as string).(variablename as string) to retrieve the values. Check if you can use them too.

Regards

Maheshvara